# jQuery hiding a div on click outside

Tags: jquery, click, show-hide

I would like to build a simple menu for each list element clicked on but hide this div once you click outside it. Here is some simple code which hopefully will make sense.

```
$('.drillFolder').click(function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('data-folder');
    $(".drillDownFolder ul li > a").attr('data-id', id);
    $(".drillDownFolder").show();
});

$("body").click(function(e){
    if(e.target.className !== "drillDownFolder")
    {
      $(".drillDownFolder").hide();
    }       
});

//The hidden div
<div class="drillDownFolder" style="display:none">
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="">Show Image</a></li>
        <li><a href="#" data-id="">Edit Image</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

I know whats wrong as the menu is show via the .drillFolder links the body click is then hiding it straight away. How can I avoid this.

Thank you if you can advise

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can stop the click event from propagating out of the .drillFolder callback with [stopPropagation()](http://api.jquery.com/event.stopPropagation/).

```
$('.drillFolder').click(function(event){
    event.stopPropagation();
    var id = $(this).attr('data-folder');
    $(".drillDownFolder ul li > a").attr('data-id', id);
    $(".drillDownFolder").show();
});

$("body").click(function(e){
    $(".drillDownFolder").hide();
});
```

Comment: Man that was so easy. TY ever so much.

Answer (score 0):

```
isClicked = function($i, e){
  return $i.length>0 && $(e.target).parents().andSelf().index($i)>-1  ;
}
```

$i is the jQuery object like $('#myDiv'), e is the event object

```
$(document).click(function(e) { 
    if( !isClicked( $('#myDiv') , e ) ) alert('not myDiv '); 
});
```